# Git not using config settings to set name for default branch upon initializing a repository

Tags: git

This is probably a stupid question, but I can't seem to figure out a solution myself. I want the default branch name to be automatically set to main when I create a repo, but it is being set to master. When I run "git config --global init.defaultBranch", it returns "main". However, when I initialize a repo and run "git status", it says that the branch is "master". Any ideas for how to fix this? Possibly related info - I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows using WSL2. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%20%22init.defaultBranch%22

Comment: You need to upgrade to `git` version 2.28+

Comment: Wow, I really am an idiot. Thanks for the help.